# Power BI counting names separated by a Semicolon

Tags: powerbi

I imported a csv table to Power BI with the following format.

| company | products | discounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A; B | X |
| 2 | B; C; D | Y |
| 3 | C; A; B ; E | X |
| 4 | F | Y |

Then, I would like to plot a chart / create a table to count the number of companies with discounts on each products.

| Products | counts for not discounts (X) | counts with discounts (Y) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| D | 0 | 1 |
| E | 1 | 0 |
| F | 0 | 1 |

Given the products names are separated by ; in the original cell, how can I count those product names separately in Power BI?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally I think you should split the values in the table into its own row. Go to Transform data > Transform > Split by Delimiter. You then can choose the ";" as the delimiter. The PowerQuery of the step would look something like:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Products.1", type text}, {"Products.2", type text}})
```

Then you can do Unpivot column to flip these 2 columns into rows. Still in Transform tab, you can locate Unpivot. Keep the company and discount columns and unpivot the products ones. PowerQuery should be like:

```
= Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"company", "discount"}, "Attribute", "Value")
```

The remaining steps to bring this onto the table you want should be straightforward I think. Hope this helps